# Appending to the same string with different arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, scripting

Ruby noob here. I have multiple arrays in a ruby script I want to append to create a single string with key values pairs where each value of an id array matches the equivalent value of an id_desc array like this:

```
ids = [1234, 2345, 3456]
ids_desc = ["inst1", "inst2", "inst3"]
```

How can I build the following string exactly as noted from the above arrays:

```
"The key for id '#{id}' has a value of '#{id_desc}'"
```

which should output:

```
"The key for id '1234' has a value of 'inst1'"
"The key for id '2345' has a value of 'inst2'"
etc.
```

I can do the following easily enough:

```
str1 = Array.new
ids.each do |id|
 str1 << "The key for id '#{id}'"
end
```

however, I'm having trouble identifying how to add "has a value of #{id_desc}" to the end of each of those key mappings.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip `ids` array if `ids`  and `ids_desc` have same length:

```
ids.zip(ids_desc).each do |id, desc|
  str1 << "The key for id #{id} has a value of #{desc}"
end
```

Or just use `Enumerable#each_with_index`:

```
ids.each_with_index do |id, i|
  str1 << "The key for id #{id} has a value of #{ids_desc[i]}"
end
```

And you can avoid creating `str1` array, using `Array#map`:

```
ids.zip(ids_desc).map do |id, desc|
  "The key for id #{id} has a value of #{desc}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Collect Strings

```
ids = [1234, 2345, 3456]
ids_desc = ["inst1", "inst2", "inst3"]
array = ids.zip(ids_desc).map { |e| "The key for id '%d' has a value of '%s'" % e }
```

### Print Collection to Standard Output

```
array.map { |e| puts e }
```

> The key for id '1234' has a value of 'inst1'
>   The key for id '2345' has a value of 'inst2'
>   The key for id '3456' has a value of 'inst3'